# Song Identification Request, Touhou?

Tags: music, touhou-project

Does anyone know the name of this song?  I think the base song is from Touhou?  But I can't remember from which game it is.

I really just need the original song name and I could probably find this particular arrangement, but it'd be great if the circle who made this arrangement was given as well.

Here's the [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TP16VibQUl0).

Answer (score 1):

As Gao indicated, the BGM corresponds to [（BGM：【DiGiTAL WiNG】Paranoia）](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61-RF-q7RmI)as indicated in the video description.

The original song is [Koishi Komeiji's Theme - Hartmann's Youkai Girl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4syvy2vjvQY)